# Can you specify a library group variable dynamically in a pipeline job

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get a variable value that lives in an Azure DevOps Library Group.

Normally, you would get it like this in, say, a PowerShell script of an Azure Pipeline job:

```
$(libraryVariableName)
```

However, I was wondering instead of the hard-coded value 'libaryVariableName' could I use a variable instead:

```
$testVarName = 'librayVariableName'
#then try to get the value like this:

$($testVarName)
```

But this doesn't work, it just prints out 'libraryVariableName' instead of the actual value

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you mean by "library variable name"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: maybe `Get-Variable $testVarName -ValueOnly` is what you're looking for?

Comment: If you're looking for a solution _in PowerShell code_, see the next comment. However, this won't work you're looking for a solution at the level of an _Azure macro_ (`$(<name>)`), which has nothing to do with PowerShell per se.

Comment: For _variable indirection_ in PowerShell, where you refer to a variable _indirectly_, via its name stored in a different variable or provided by an expression, use the [`Get-Variable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) and [`Set-Variable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlets, but note that there are usually better alternatives, such as hashtables.